# What happens when I perform this as root

Tags: linux, unix

*(don't try this!)*

```
lsof  -i | head 100 | xargs rm-r
```

After executing this I'm not able to login as it removed `/bin/bash`. Reboot also don't work. Shows kernel error and server crashed.

Comment: What possessed you to run a line of code including the rm command as root without understanding what the line does? Restore the machine from your backups and learn from this mistake.

Comment: We used to get newbies in the multiplayer game Homeworld to type `ACCESS` as a cheat code (it would actually scuttle all your ships). I can only assume this is that sort of scenario. **Don't run shell commands you don't understand.**

Answer (score 7):

You will need to reinstall the operating system.

`lsof -l` lists open files

`head -100` returns the top 100

`xargs rm -r` recursively delete them

You've likely deleted 100 random open files, including things like shared libraries and core utilities. The OS is now unusable.